# Tiles and breadcrumb - Don't want final breadcrumb to link

Tags: tiles, struts-1

I'm using struts 1.x and tiles.  I want to create a breadcrumb trail containing a path to the current page, but, I don't want the final breadcrumb to point to the current page.  This is because the final page is the result of a search. So it doesn't make sense to point to a search result page.

How do I add a breadcrumb that is only a label and not a link?

I'd like it to look like:

```
Home Page (link) > Search Criteria (link) > Search Results (not a link)
```

My tiles def looks like:

```
<putList name="breadCrumbList">
    <item value="Home Page" link="/blablabla" />
    <item value="Search Criteria" link="/blablabla2" />
    <item value="Search Results" link="/blablabla2" />  <-- this needs changed
</putList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the link value to # as follows.

```
<item value="Search Results" link="#" />
```

**EDIT :**

This is what we have done in our project if that helps:

```
   <definition name="tile.success" extends=".layout">
        <put name="content" value="/jsp/routing.jsp"/>
        <put name="title.section" value="My Title"/>
        <putList name="breadcrumbs">
            <item link="#" value="Add Name"/>
        </putList>
    </definition>
```

"Add Name" just shows up as a label in the breadcrumb.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Susie.  Your suggestion didn't work though.  It is still a function link - which isn't desired.  And, the link results in a page not found error.

Comment: We are currently using struts 1.2 and that's what we've done and it seems to work. Did you restart the server after you made the change?

Comment: Thanks Susie.  What you stated does work.  My app is converting the "#" to the application path + #.  e.g. www.mysite.com/application/mypage.jsp containing the breadcrumb specified above gets converted to **www.mysite.com/application#**.  If I manually convert the resulting anchor link in Chrome from **www.mysite.com/application#** to **#** it works perfectly.